# Is it possible to deploy cgi based web page in github gh-pages branch

Tags: perl, github, deployment, cgi

As we know in github gh-pages branch we can deploy html file.

In a similar way i want to deploy cgi based webpage script in github gh-pages branch.

If possible to deploy the script can you share me the procedure to deploy script.

I use perl program in CGI.

Comment: CGI scripts are server side. You can not deploy arbitrary code on someone elses servers.

Answer (score 2):

No. Github would be insane to allow people to run random CGI code on their servers. Github are not insane :-)